# Does someone know about Open-source in python imports or libs?

Tags: python, open-source

i have a question for you. Python is open source, that's what I know.
But are libs and imports also open source? For example I import the tkinter and the snap7 Lib for my project, is this all open source? Or only when I write a python script without any imports. Because Iam programming a script for my company I work for. I can only do this if its all open source :)
Thanks for answers!

Comment: you're mixing source openness and licensing. your boss doesn't care if it's open-source, he just wants that the license of the libraries you're using are compatible with the one of your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it written in [python website](https://www.python.org/about/) : "Python is developed under an OSI-approved open source license, making it freely usable and distributable, even for commercial use. Python's license is administered by the Python Software Foundation."

So the answer is yes , it's still open source.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Everything in the standard libraries is open source, as it comes with python itself.

This does not exclude that you can use an external package installed through `pip` (or any other source) under a different licence, or even a closed source library (altough those are... rare; since the language itself is not ideal for distributing closed source code.
unless we talk web development but that's another topic)

To reply to your question specifically, [snap7 is under MIT](https://github.com/gijzelaerr/python-snap7/blob/master/LICENSE)  and [tkinter is included in cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/main/Lib/tkinter), so it's under [the same licence](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/LICENSE).